# My comment system in Django is not working as expected

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm creating an application where a user can create their own posts, and other users can comment on the posts.

I have already tried retrieving comments from the database, and displaying them for that certain post, however this has been unsuccessful

Here is my code to tackle this problem:

views.py

```
 def comment(request, pk):
        form = CommentForm()
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=pk)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                comment = Comment()
                comment.body =  form.cleaned_data['body']
                comment.user = request.user
                comment.post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
                comment.save()
                return redirect('home')
                return render(request, 'posts/comments.html')
            else:
                return render(request, 'posts/comments.html', {'error': 'Please submit valid data'})

        else:
            return render(request, 'posts/comments.html', {'form': form}, {'comments': comments})
```

comments.html

```
 {% block content %}
      <div class="container">
        {% for com in comments.all %}
           <p>{{ com.body }}</p>
          <br>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if error %}
        {{ error }}
        <br>
        <br>
        {% endif %}
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <form method="post">
          <h2> Comment</h2>

          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> 
 Comment</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
   class Comment(models.Model):
        body = models.CharField(max_length=130)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.body
```

urls.py

```
path('create/', post_views.Create.as_view(), name='create'),
path('post/<int:pk>/', post_views.DetailPost.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('comment/<int:pk>/', post_views.comment, name='comment'),
```

urls.py for home

```
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #HOME
    path('', post_views.home, name='home'),
```

This is expected to display a posts comments when a button is pressed to  view the post, however the comments do not show. [See this here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS0Od.png)

Comment: Are your posts getting saved and you are redirecting to the home url?

Comment: Yes, and the . comment gets left on the comment.html page for the post.

Comment: Will you please paste home urls.py as well? and one more suggestion try removing the "return render(request, 'posts/comments.html')" after return redirect() and then run it.

Comment: I have removed the return render before the redirect, and the issue still occurs. I have added my urls.py in now aswell.

Comment: I am sorry I meant the urls.py for the app where the redirection is ('home') ... Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: No worries i have added it in aswell

Comment: @djangoninja I believe you have to specify that you want to select on the post primary key: `Comment.objects.filter(post__pk=pk)`

Comment: Hello, thank you but i switched out the code, and the comments still wont display in comments.html

Comment: Try making the for loop in the template be `for com in comments`. `comments` is evaluated as a list when you pass it in to `render`, you don't need to explicitly say `.all`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have removed the .all but, however the same results occur.

Comment: Add `print(comments[:])` to your view just to verify that there are in fact results coming back

Comment: Yes. The result is: [<Comment: ss>, <Comment: sss>, <Comment: poosif>, <Comment: pposf>, <Comment: yoo>, <Comment: hello>, <Comment: hello>, <Comment: helo>]> .   Which are my comment objects.

Comment: @djangoninja Ok this should be the final fix. In your render call you are passing the form and the comments as two different parameters. It should read: `{'form': form, 'comments': comments}`

Comment: Thank you so much man! It finally worked.